# Insert an array of objects into mongodb with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Now I am using clmtrackr library to detect emotions from the webcam and I want to save this emotions Here is my node.js code to save the values in mongodb

```
 exports.storeemotion = function (emotions, callback){

  var eshema= new emotioncollection({ 

    emotions: [emotions]
  });
  eshema.save(function(err) {

          }); 
  callback({"status":"emotion remote done"});
}
```

and the schema code is

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;
//var bcrypt         = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// search results schema 
var ResultaSchema   = new Schema({

 emotions:[{emotion: String, value: String}]
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('emotioncollection',ResultaSchema);
```

emotions should be like that ([check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Oxij.png)).

but the mongo saved an empty array ([check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqaqL.png)).

Comment: What is the content of [emotions] ?

Comment: you can check the content of emotions in the picture that I attribut

Answer (score 0):

The `emotions` parameters of your `storeemotion` function is already an array, so you just have to pass that parameters as is, not in another array:

```
exports.storeemotion = function (emotions, callback) {

  var eshema = new emotioncollection({ 
    emotions: emotions  // <= your schema already expects an array of objects
  });
  eshema.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return callback({"status": "error"});
    callback({"status": "emotion remote done"});
  });
}
```

Comment: this is what i thought in the beginig but an error apears to me like that ValidationError: emotions: Cast to Array failed for value "[ '{"emotion":"angry","value":0.04704075628141234}',
  '{"emotion":"sad","value":0.1901717114090776}',
  '{"emotion":"surprised","value":0.1427212765004795}',
  '{"emotion":"happy","value":0.021942792186878515}',
  '{"emotion":"female","value":0.8954360830214716}',
  '{"emotion":"male","value":0.1045639169785285}' ]" at path "emotions"

Comment: You have to pass an array of object, not an array of JSON strings.